# CONTAINS with boundary across multiple words in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to do a CONTAINS with boundaries across MULTIPLE words in neo4j. Any advice?

EQUIVALENT OF:

```
MATCH (a)-[:REL]->(b)
WHERE b.whole CONTAINS a.part
RETURN a.part, b.whole
```

Would return:
"Peter","Peter Andrew Morrison"
"Andrew","Peter Andrew Morrison"
"Sarah Morgan","Sarah Morgan Wilkerson"

Would not return 
"Pete","Peter Andrew Morrison"
"Pete Andrew","Peter Andrew Morrison"
"Sara","Sarah Morgan Wilkerson"

Is regex the way to go? If so, how do you add the a.part in regex? I tried

```
WHERE b.whole=~'.*'+a.part+'.*'
```

but that returns an error.

Or should I splice b.whole into a list and do b.part in list?

```
WITH b, a, split(b.whole, ' ') as list 
WHERE a.part in list
```

But this only allows one word at a time and I need multiple word matches... any thoughts? 
TIA!!!

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "contains" will also work for strings inside a string and does not need to be the whole word.  Try this cypher below and it returns true.

```
RETURN "Peter Andrew Morrison" CONTAINS "Pete" 
true
```

The problem is there is no such node "a" where a.part equals "Pete".  Copy below cypher and run it in your neo4j. You will see 0 row.

```
MATCH (a)-[:REL]->(b) 
WHERE a.part = "Pete" 
RETURN a
```

Thus, if node "a" for Pete does not exists or/and is not connected to b then you will not get "Pete","Peter Andrew Morrison" in the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response -sorry mine is so late as I went on break. The tricky part for me is having Peter not come back when I search for Pete. Is there a way to force Neo4j "contains" to respect word boundaries so that a word search does not return TRUE if it's part of a bigger word.